# php classのオブジェクトをInstantiateしてClass内Public VariableのEchoの仕方

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $name = "Nobu Kim";
    $age = 42;

    $user1 = new User('Nobu', '42');
    echo $user1->username; //doesn't get printed
    echo $user1->age; //doesn't get printed
    //print_r($user1);
    //test->__destruct(); cannot call explicitly
    echo "wtf"; //gets printed
    echo $name; //gets printed
    //echo $user1;

    class User
    {
        public $username;
        public $age;

        function __construct($name, $age)
        {
            //Constructor statements here
            $username = $name;
            echo $username; //gets printed
            $age = $age;
            echo $age; //gets printed
        }
    }


        function __destruct()
        {
            //Destructor code here
        }



?>
```

上記、何故コメントにて”Doesn't get printed"のライン、`echo $user1->username` & `echo $user1->age;`はプリントされないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***上記、何故コメントにて”Doesn't get printed"のライン、echo $user1->username & echo $user1->age;はプリントされないのでしょうか。***

該当のプロパティの値がどちらも空(`null`)だからです。

PHPでは、コンストラクタやインスタンスメソッドのコンテキストでも、インスタンスのプロパティをアクセスするには`$this->`のようにオブジェクト演算子(`->`)を使うことが必須になっています。

```
    function __construct($name, $age)
    {
        //Constructor statements here
        $this->username = $name;
        echo $this->username;
        $this->age = $age;
        echo $this->age;
    }
```

あなたの元のコードでコンストラクタ内の2つの代入文、`$username = $name`は、ローカル変数`$username`(PHPのローカル変数には宣言は要らない)に代入しているだけ(ローカル変数はプロパティの`$username`とは別物)、`$age = $age`は引数として宣言された`$age`にそれ自身を代入しているだけになります。

Comment: 参考になりました。教科書に載っていて確かに読みましたが、他のStackOverflowの書き込みを読んで必要ないと思いましたが、間違ってました。

Comment: 実際にやってみるまではうまく理解できていなかったり、ネットの記事の中にはちょっとした間違いがあっても修正されずにそのままなんてこともあったりします。ここのようなQ&Aサイトもうまく利用しながら学習を進めてください。